# How to pattern-match against every numeric class in one case?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Suppose I have

```
def foo(x: Any) = x match {
  case s: String => println(0)
  case i: Int => println(1)
  case l: Long => println(2)
  //...
}
```

Is there any way to make something like the following?

```
def foo(x: Any) = x match {
  case s: String => println(0)
  case i: Numeric => println("Numeric")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could match against the `Number` interface:

```
def foo(x: Any) = x match {
  case s: String => println(0)
  case i: java.lang.Number => println("Numeric")
}
```

Comment: This kind of matching is discouraged as it's synonym for type-casting, which is possible but is considered 'bad style' in functional programming.

Comment: Well there is no idiomatic way is there, so this is rather encouraged for this scenario - till Scala catches up with Java..

Answer (score 5):

You could try this:

```
def foo[A](x: A)(implicit num: Numeric[A] = null) = Option(num) match {
  case Some(num) => println("Numeric: " + x.getClass.getName)
  case None => println(0)
}
```

Then this

```
foo(1)
foo(2.0)
foo(BigDecimal(3))
foo('c')
foo("no")
```

will print

```
Numeric: java.lang.Integer
Numeric: java.lang.Double
Numeric: scala.math.BigDecimal
Numeric: java.lang.Character
0
```

Note that obtaining a `null` implicit parameter would not mean that no such implicit exist, but just that none was found at compile time in the search scope for implicits.

Comment: That is a tricky one! What a pity I can't accept both answers.

Comment: Is there a (nice) way to avoid the `null` value? (E.g. providing an implicit `Option[Numeric[A]]`?)

Comment: All tricks that I can think of would be considerably less readable and not substantially safer.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: I noticed that this solution does not work if the numeric values are typed as `Any` and then passed to the method, e.g. `val x: Any = 3.14; foo(x)` will print `0`. In that case, only the solution of the accepted answer is working as intended. I need this functionality because I want to extract any numeric value as `double` from `Map[String, Any]`. Is there some way to change this method to work with `Any` as well? I prefer using `Numeric` instead of pattern matching `java.lang.Number`.

Comment: Right. Implicits are a compile-time mechanism, and if the compiler thinks it's passing an `Any`, it can't supply a `Numeric`.