# Using asInstanceOf to convert Any to Double

Tags: scala

I have a function that takes a variable number of arguments.  The first is a String and the rest are numbers (either Int or Double) so I am using Any* to get the arguments.  I would like to treat the numbers uniformly as Doubles, but I cannot just use asInstanceOf[Double] on the numeric arguments.  For example:

```
 val arr = Array("varargs list of numbers", 3, 4.2, 5)
 val d = arr(1).asInstanceOf[Double]
```

gives:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

Is there a way to do this?  (The function needs to add up all the numbers).

Comment: Have a look at this issue: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1448 We are yet unsure in which direction we're going to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Scala's `asInstanceOf` is its name for casting. Casting is not converting.

What you want can be accomplished like this:

```
val mongrel = List("comment", 1, 4.0f, 9.00d)
val nums = mongrel collect { case i: Int => i case f: Float => f case d: Double => d }
val sumOfNums = nums.foldLeft(0.0) ((sum, num) => sum + num)
```

Comment: I believe you can just use the `sum` method on [`List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) for the last part, ie: `nums.sum`

Comment: Love the name of the `List` val.

Comment: Im new to scala. Could someone explain what the case statements mean?  Like it its of type Int... let it be Int? I dont get how the nums became a List[Double] from mongrel which was a List[Any]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a slight simplification of Randall's answer:

```
val mongrel = List("comment", 1, 4.0f, 9.00d)
val nums = mongrel collect { case i: java.lang.Number => i.doubleValue() }
val sumOfNums = nums.sum
```

Matching for any kind of number turns out to be a little tricky in Scala, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757095/how-to-pattern-match-against-every-numeric-class-in-one-case) for another way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

When there is a need to handle different types, you should avoid casting them and instead use a pattern match. To add up all Double's and Int's of an array you could use:

```scala
val array = Array("varargs list of numbers", 3, 4.2, 5)

array.foldLeft(0.0){ 
  case (s, i: Int) => s + i
  case (s, d: Double) => s + d
  case (s, _) => s
}
```

The pattern match allows you to treat each different type separately and avoids running into `ClassCastExceptions`.

Answer (score 1):

Stepping back for a moment, might it be easier to have the function take `Double*` instead of `Any*`?

```
scala> def foo(str: String, nums: Double*) { 
    nums foreach { n => println(s"num: $n, class:   ${n.getClass}") } 
}
foo: (str: String, nums: Double*)Unit

scala> foo("", 1, 2.3)
num: 1.0, class: double
num: 2.3, class: double
```